# syntax error in ruby script when using selenium webdriver (Windows 7)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am using Ruby 2.2.4 and Selenium webdriver version 2.53.0.

My scripts were running fine, but suddenly I am seeing this error:

> "C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:1242:in `require': C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected keyword_return, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
>   rubysl-wein return gem_original_require(path)
>   from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:1242:in`'
>       from :1:in `require'
>       from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in`'

## MY CODE

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http://google.com"
```

I am seeing this error while opening any site.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. This is probably a `Windows 7` bug, try bundling you code and now get out

Comment: How is code bundled ?. And I have used selenium scripts past one year  in windows 7 and did not get this error before

Comment: see https://github.com/bundler/bundler

Comment: @Damiano are you suggesting downloading bundler ?